# Массивы с индексами перечисляемого типа в C++

Tags: c++

Возможно ли в C++ создать массив с индексами перечислимого типа? Если да, то как? Вариант, который мне известен на Delphi

```
...  
MyType = (one, two, three);    
...  
a: array [MyType] of integer;     
...  
a[one] := 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Возможно ли в с++ создать массив с индексами перечислимого типа?

Ответ - да.

> Если да, то как?

Самое простое, что приходит в голову: "перечислимый тип" - это enum. Т.е. по сути набор целых констант. Затем их можно легко использовать как индексы в массиве. Главное - не вылезти за пределы массива.
Более сложный вариант - сделать свой пользовательский класс, который будет перегружать оператор []. Это открывает очень широкие возможности. Например, можно сделать разреженный массив с автоматическим выделением места под новые элементы с семантикой обычного массива.

Answer (score 3):

Единственный вариант который приходит в голову, это добавить последний член, который будет давать нам размер enum-а:

```
enum MyType {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    MyTypeSize
};

int arr[MyTypeSize];
```

Answer (score 1):

а тебе сильно жмет?

```
enum MyType {a, b, c, d};  
int i[d];  
for (MyType x = 0; x < d; x++)
{  
  i[x]=x;  
}
```

Comment: ну, я же только для примера написал, что индекс=содержимому массива.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо ответили на StackOverflow:
[Using an enum as an array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404231/using-an-enum-as-an-array-index)